# file handling in python to create text file

Tags: python-3.x, file, datetime, append, mkdir

```
import os
from datetime import datetime, date

current_datetime = datetime.now()
str_current_datetime = str(current_datetime)
today = date.today()
today = today.isoformat()
if not os.path.exists('today'):
    os.makedirs(today)
    f = open(os.path.join(today, 'logs.txt'), 'w')
    f.write("------------------------------------------")
    f.write("\n")
    f.write("date & time: ")
    f.write(str_current_datetime)
    f.write("\n")
    f.write("Log        : File running")
    f.write("\n")
    f.write("------------------------------------------")
    f.write("\n")
    f.close()

else:
    f = open('logs.txt', 'w')
    f.write("------------------------------------------")
    f.write("\n")
    f.write("date & time: ")
    f.write(str_current_datetime)
    f.write("\n")
    f.write("Log        : File running")
    f.write("\n")
    f.write("------------------------------------------")
    f.write("\n")
    f.close()
```

This is my code to write file in directory and able to create it but when i tried to create second time it shows the below error please suggest me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/abhi1254/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/newassign/date.py", line 9, in <module>
    os.makedirs(today)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 223, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: '2022-05-24'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement checks if there is a folder named "today", since the parameter provided is string. What you wanted to achieve is to check for the `today` **variable**.
Because of this your code will always perform first part of your conditional statement (as long as there is no folder named "today") and will always run command `os.makedirs(today)`, however `os.makedirs` [by default](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs) raises exception if folder with given name already exists.

Try simply removing quotation marks, like this:

```py
today = today.isoformat()

if not os.path.exists(today):
```

Comment: Yep that was totally it,  it was something very simple i was over looking been look at it for a while. Thank you so much!!